# Find what network range user is on?

Tags: networking, bash

I am making a network scanner that will work on any network. This is my code so far

```
fd=$(date +%m%d%y%H%M%S)
echo -e "IP$fd\nReport of IP addresses on this intranet, test started at \n$(date)\n\nThe following IP addresses were found:" > IP$fd.txt
echo -e " Okay. Mind you, this could take a couple of minutes.\nI'll be scanning all 254 possibilities between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.254\nI will ring the system bell when I am done.\nHere we go..."
for i in 192.168.0.{1..254}
do
echo "scanning $i"
if [ "$(ping -q -c1 $i)" ]
then
echo -e "AHA! Got one! ---- $i is up!"
fi
echo "END SCAN"
done
echo -e "That's all I got.\Test completed at\n$(date)\n" >> IP$fd.txt
echo -e \\a
echo -e "Your report is IP$fd.txt, and this is what it says:\n"
exit
```

Except the problem is that this will only work if your IP range is 192.168.0.1-255. It won't return anything if the ip is 10.10.10.1.

Is there anyway I can get the users network range and apply it to my script?

**Edit: I am running as root**

Comment: Can you do a DHCP request and from that gather an IP and network mask? (Though doing that from user mode might be *interesting*).

Comment: No, I am running this script as *root*. I'll be fine with whatever you can think of

Comment: is this a fantastically elaborate way of doing `nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24' ??

Comment: No. I need this to work *without* installing stuff. Is there anyway you can run a command for *each* IP that is up?

Comment: @TheDeveloper I think he means user mode as opposed to kernel mode. Kernel mode is lower-level and gives much more direct hardware access (as you could guess from the name), and is generally used by the kernel and drivers. User mode is more restricted for stability reasons - a kernel mode bug _will_ crash the system. Even though you're `root`, you're still in user mode.

Comment: Well, DHCP is almost always done in user mode... On the other hand, it does require root privileges, to bind to the low ports.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way.

On Linux, you can list all IPv4 subnets the host belongs to using:

```
ip -4 route show scope link | awk '{print $1}'
```

(Note that there can be **more than one**.)

Comment: That's an important note: A computer can have as many IPs as you want. It's not restricted to a single network. Any method will have to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the current network details from the output of `ifconfig -a`

From that you should be able to set up variables for your for-loop. It might be easier to work with integer addresses rather than dotted-quads.

There will be multiple address-ranges, some of them IPV4 and some IPV6.

To detect nearby networks to which the current machine is not directly connected would take a lot more work.

Comment: I recommend avoiding `ifconfig` for this, as its output is not stable (it has changed *a lot* in net-tools 1.60), and it *still* does not support multiple IPv4 addresses per interface.